# For a given function get its parent object

Tags: javascript

Lets say i have this code:

```
function GetParentObject(fn){
   //get parent object from function

}

var obj = GetParentObject(eval); //returns window
```

How do i implement GetParentObject function?

Comment: Are you assuming your function (fn) will return a DOM element when invoked?

Comment: @StevenSpungin - Given the example, presumably not.

Answer (score 0):

This is where [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) comes in.

The `this` keyword returns the object that owns the function where it is called.